# define xml payload in transform message or set payload in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I need to define the below payload in transform message to send to different system but while adding in transform message or set payload component it's giving error.

Please let me know how i can define this as payload in transform message component or how i can convert it to json and convert again to xml before sending to http requester?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/enveloper/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <env:Body>
      <wd:GetMappingTable xmlns:wd="urn:com.xyz/abcd" wd:version="v40.0">
     <wd:RequestRef>
          <wd:MappingRef>
              <wd:MappingId wd:type="Integration_Mapping_ID">ACCOUNT_MP</wd:MappingId>
          </wd:MappingRef>
     </wd:RequestRef>
       <wd:ResponseFil>
         <wd:page>1</wd:page>
         <wd:count>10</wd:count>
       </wd:ResponseFil>
   </wd:GetMappingTable>
   </env:Body>
 </env:Envelope>
```

Comment: "it's giving error" that is not an appropriate way to ask here. What is the actual error? What is the actual Transform element? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you want to generate the XML as the output from a DataWeave script. I used a hack to generate the `xmlns:xsd` namespace because DataWeave will not write a namespace not used. If you can avoid using it just remove that attribute from Envelope. The script shows the method, you can fill the few remaining elements using it as an example.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns env http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/enveloper/
ns wd urn:com.xyz/abcd
---
{ 
    env#Envelope @("xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"): {
        env#Body: {
            wd#GetMappingTable @(wd#version:"v40.0"): {
                wd#RequestRef: {
                    wd#MappingRef @(wd#'type':""): "ACCOUNT_MP"
                },
                wd#ResponseFil: "TO DO"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/enveloper/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <env:Body>
    <wd:GetMappingTable xmlns:wd="urn:com.xyz/abcd" wd:version="v40.0">
      <wd:RequestRef>
        <wd:MappingRef wd:type="">ACCOUNT_MP</wd:MappingRef>
      </wd:RequestRef>
      <wd:ResponseFil>TO DO</wd:ResponseFil>
    </wd:GetMappingTable>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```